# How to indicate whether the improvement of a ranking is statistically significant over another one in R?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, t-test, ranking

I have two ranked lists of documents (List1, List2). After comparing each of them against the ground truth, I calculate precision at 5 (P@5) metric to measure how good are each of the ranked lists. List1 outperforms List2.

Now, I would like to test and see if the improvement of List1 over List2 is statistically significant. Here are List1 and List2:

List1 = Doc10, Doc21, Doc2, Doc3, ...

List2 = Doc2, Doc10, Doc3, Doc21, ...

I have looked into the literature, and usually they do t-test for this matter, but I couldn't find any tutorials which explains how to do it in a tool such as R. I will appreciate if anyone can help me.

EDIT: In order to give you an example of a scientific paper in my area which has done it, please check this paper: http://romaindeveaud.github.io/publis/cikm15-deveaud.pdf

If you check the caption for Table 2, it says:

> We use a two-sided pairwise t-test (with p < 0.05) to determine statistically significant differences over: (1) a random baseline that generates random category
>   distributions ...

Note that each method returns a ranked list for each given query (or given user). Then, for each query in each system P@5 is calculated and each system's overall performance is the average of all P@5 values for each query. As an example:

```
           System 1          System 2
Query 1    P@5=0.5           P@5=0.6
Query 2    P@5=0.6           P@5=0.7
Query 3    P@5=0.7           P@5=0.8
---------------------------------------
Overall    P@5=0.6           P@5=0.7
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: you already know what you want (t-test) and are asking how to do a t-test in R? (although I don't see how a t-test can be used with that data...)

Comment: @Slowloris I know how to t-test in R. My question is how can I conduct t-test in such data (two different rankings)?

Comment: @Slowloris I can't see how a t-test can be used either. However, there are many papers saying: "we did a pairwise t-test to see if our improvements are statistically significant" and I can't figure our how one possibly can do it.

Comment: I see.. you might edit your question to replace "how to do it in a tool such as R" with "How can this be done with this sort of data", since your question is about what kind of statistical method makes sense to use and not about how to do something in R per se. I also would like to see one of these papers, maybe if you post a link and/or an excerpt from a paper describing the kind of analysis you are talking about, that might help someone figure out what they are doing and if it makes sense.

Comment: @Slowloris Good point. Thanks for the tip. I'll edit the question asap.

Comment: @Slowloris Just edited. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I don't know much about this particular use case, but I have seen similiar tests with the following intuition: If both rankings are the same ($H_0$), then differences between the rankings can be viewed as random with mean 0. This you can test with a t-test under suitable distributional assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you store your P@5 metrics in a couple of R vectors, say `rs1` and `rs2` you can carry out the t-test comparing their mean values as:

```
t.test (rs1, rs2)
```

This will compute a **two sides** **unpaired** test assuming **unequal variances**.

In your case, it seems that your alternative hypothesis is just one side so you can use the `alternative` parameter in the `t.test` function

```
t.test (rs1, rs2, alternative = "greater")
```

that will test for the alternative hypothesis that the mean value in `rs1` is **greater** than the mean value in `rs2` (check if this is the direction you need... it assumes that the greater the score the better the ranking)

You may also want to assume that the variance in both scores is the same. The use:

```
t.test (rs1, rs2, alternative = "greater", var.equal = TRUE)
```

Finally, if your samples are **paired** (I guess this means that your two lists contain different scores but for the same documents), you can use the `paired` parameter:

```
t.test (rs1, rs2, alternative = "greater", paired = TRUE)
```

**Notice** that in the **paired** analysis `rs1` and `rs2` should be in the same "order" meaning that each position in both vectors should refer to the same document... If you have named vectors in your R session you can reorder `rs2` as `rs1` doing:

```
rs2 <- rs2[names (rs1)]
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have an additional question just to make sure that this solution fits my need.
Assume that for example, instead of calculating P@5 for each query and then averaging on them, I would extract the top 5 documents (result) for every query and then calculate the precision of the model on those items (which will be P@5 for the whole system again). How would you check if the system's performance is statistically significant in this case?

Comment: I am not sure to completely understand the question... Do you want to compare the top 5 documents in System1 with their corresponding System2? Or with the top 5 System2 without matching?

Comment: No not exactly. I'm saying instead of having P@5 for each query and then averaging, if I have one precision of all top 5 documents per query. Let's make it simpler, assume it's a classification problem (a binary one) and I want to see whether the precision of my system is better than the other one. How would you do that?

Comment: Is a very general question Moh. Having the two lists of P@5 metrics you can use many methods to compare them. I explained the t-test because you asked for it but Jaques for instance mentioned the `wilcox.test` and there are many other available. The best option will depend somehow on the distribution of your P@5 which I am not familiar with. But now you are talking about selecting top elements (which implies some sort of categorization of your ranking) and about precision which will need something like a gold standard to compare the two methods against...

Comment: Sorry if I confused you with my comment, I'm asking this because there are some cases in which we don't have P@5's for every query but instead we have all the retrieved documents and the gold standard. I'm now well aware how to test the significance in the case which you explained in your answer. It would be  great if you could give me some hints for the other case... Thanks.

Comment: No worries. The "fold standard" is  System1/System2 for each document?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40606/discussion-between-moh-and-dmontaner).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to answer on two levels.

1) How to compare **rankings**? To compare the full rankings of the two systems you need a) the correct ranking, or a ground truth ranking and b) you need a measure that tells how tow rankings are similar. This question [Can I compare ordinal rankings (and if so, how)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29560/can-i-compare-ordinal-rankings-and-if-so-how) on CV discusses 2 metrics to compare rankings. Notice that in this case you will be comparing the ranking of system 1 with the ground truth and then the ranking of system 2 to the ground truth, for each query or user. Then you will have something similar to the figure in your question, but instead of P@5, you may have the Kendal tau or the Spearman rho.

But you may have settled in using P@5, which is not *really* comparing the full ranking of the two systems, but only how right they are on the first 5 entries. It is OK, if the publications in your area use P@5, you should use P@5.

Which brings us to the second level, given that you have the sequence of measures (either Kendal tau, or Spearman rho or P@5) for System 1 and for System 2, for each query, how you should perform the test

2) How to perform a significance test on two sequences of measures for System 1 and System 2?

Here, @dmontaner is basically correct and describes the mechanics of using the functions on R, but I will be a little bit more incisive.

If you are going to use a t-test than you should use this solution proposed by @dmontaner

```
t.test (rs1, rs2,  paired = TRUE)
```

your data is DEFINITELY paired by the query (or user). Methodologically you should not use the

```
alternative = "greater"
```

option unless you have theoretical (not empirical) reasons to believe that your system is better than the competition.

But there is an issue of whether you should or not use  t-test. If researchers in your area use t-test, if that paper you pointed out was a good paper in a good conference, that by all means use the t-test. But the t-test makes assumptions on your data that may not be true. For example, the t-test assumes your data is more or less distributed normally, and this is more important the less data you have. If you have less than 30 queries, that your data should be distributed very similar to a normal. But P@5 is usually not normally distributed (at least because it is limited to the 0-1 range). The same can be said about the other two measures (tau e rho). In this case you should use the [Wilcoxon signed rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test). Fortunately there is a R function for that, and you only call

```
    wilcox.test (rs1, rs2,  paired = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just have an additional question just to make sure that this solution fits my need.
Assume that for example, instead of calculating P@5 for each query and then averaging on them, I would extract the top 5 documents (result) for every query and then calculate the precision of the model on those items (which will be P@5 for the whole system again). How would you check if the system's performance is statistically significant in this case?